# Why is ViewGroup required for Preference.setLayoutResource input param? Or is it?

Tags: android, android-preferences

The Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference#setLayoutResource(int)) for `Preference.setLayoutResource(int layoutResId)` says

> This layout should contain a `ViewGroup` with ID `R.id.widget_frame` to be the parent of the specific widget for this Preference. It should similarly contain `R.id.title` and `R.id.summary`.

This sentence leaves me with a lot of questions. Is anyone able to give a more thorough explanation?

1. The word "should" is used. Does that mean this is just a recommended practice, or required?
2. What is meant by "contain a ViewGroup"? Does that mean the root element of the layout must be a ViewGroup (or some derivative)? Or that a ViewGroup must be present somewhere in the layout?
3. Does the root element need to have a literal id of `R.id.widget_frame`?
4. Are `R.id.title` and `R.id.summary` required attributes? Or is this just a recommendation for best practice?
5. If the layout must contain a ViewGroup with that specific id and both title and summary attributes, why does it seem to work just fine without any of those things? (I know it's not good practice to rely on undocumented behavior, I'm just looking for some kind of explanation to better understand what's going on under the hood)

Thanks in advance for the answers!

Comment: with all due respect, seems like you can test basically all (if not at least most) of these yourself, right ?

Comment: Well, as I said in #5, it seems to work without these things as far as I can tell. I'm trying to understand the _why_ here

Comment: If it is indeed a requirement, it probably isn't safe to rely on undocumented observable behavior. But it's unclear to me whether this is a requirement, or just a recommendation.